# Rasa NLU: Tensorflow embedding with entity extraction

Tags: tensorflow, spacy, rasa-nlu

Tensorflow embedding has a very good intent recogition.

In my experience it improved test results from about 45% confidence to 95% for simple inputs such as "Hello" compared to spacy.

But out of the box it does not have any entity extraction.

Is there any Pipeline configuration to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Config

The configuration below contains ner_crf for entity extraction.

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "tokenizer_whitespace"
- name: "intent_entity_featurizer_regex"
- name: "ner_crf"
- name: "ner_synonyms"
- name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
- name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"
```

---

## Usage

WebApi:

```
curl --noproxy '*' -X POST --header 'content-type: application/x-yml' --data-binary @${RASA_FILE} --url "${RASA_YML}:5000/train?project=${PROJECT}&model=${MODELNAME}"
```

The configuration is already contained within RASA_YML. [docs](http://rasa.com/docs/nlu/master/http/#post-train)

Bash:

```
python -m rasa_nlu.train -v --config ${CONFIG} --data ${RASA_MD} --path projects --project ${PROJECT} --fixed_model_name ${MODELNAME}
```

---

## Version

Rasa NLU: >=0.13.0

---

credit: [github issue](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/issues/1117#issuecomment-404414587)

Comment: This worked for me with multiple FAQs and entity recognition with good accuracy